# Showing that 5 points are on a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have the following problem. $\angle ABC$ is rotated around point $O$ so that it creates $\angle A_1B_1C_1$. Segment $A_1B_1$ intersects segment $AB$ at point $M$ and segment $B_1C_1$ intersects segment $BC$ at point $N$. Segments $A_1B_1$ and $BC$ intersect at point $P$. I need to show that points $O,M,N,B,B_1$ are concyclic. Here is what I have so far:

$\triangle ABC \equiv \triangle A_1B_1C_1\,$ ,   $\angle BPA_1=\angle B_1PC\,$ ,  $\triangle BMP\sim \triangle B_1NP$. This is enough to show that quadrilateral $MNB_1B$ is cyclic.  I am unsure how to continue from this point.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since the rotation is centered at $O$, the rotation rotates the pink angle to the yellow angle. Therefore $O,M,B,B_1$ are co-cyclic. Similar argument for $O,N,B_1,B$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look at it from that perspective.

Comment: You are welcome.